# Loop through two arrays and get a desired output using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays as follows

```
const arr1 = ['john', 'robot'];

const arr2 = [{name : 'john'}, {name : 'kevin'}, {name : 'james}];
```

My desired output is to manipulate array arr1 such that if value of arr1 is not present as a name property in arr2 it should get removed from arr1;

So in the above example after the operation, the output should be

```
console.log(arr1)  // ['john']
```

as robot is not present in arr2, it gets removed.

Likewise if I have following set of arrays

```
const names = ['sachin', 'sehwag'];

const players = [{name : 'dhoni'}, {name : 'dravid'}, {name : 'ganguly'} , {name : 'laxman}];
```

names array should be manipulated to

```
console.log(names) // []
```

as both sachin and sehwag is not present in players array

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: i tried looping names array with map method and inside the callback of map did a filter on the players array.However got stuck in getting the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use es6, a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is good for this. They only store unique values and are efficient at lookup. They give constant time lookups, which looping through an array doesn't:

```js
const arr1 = ['john', 'robot'];
const arr2 = [{name : 'john'}, {name : 'kevin'}, {name : 'james'}];

// create a set with names
let testSet = arr2.reduce((set, obj) => set.add(obj.name), new Set)

let filtered = arr1.filter(item => testSet.has(item))
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I am using ES6, hence using Set seems nice.Your solution worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can first grab all the names from array of objects `arr2`, and then filter the `arr1` based on `names` list..

```js
var arr1 = ["john", "robot"];
var arr2 = [{ name: "john" }, { name: "kevin" }, { name: "james" }];
var names = arr2.map(ob => ob.name);
console.log(arr1.filter(name => names.includes(name)));

var arr1 = ["sachin", "sehwag"];
var arr2 = [
  { name: "dhoni" },
  { name: "dravid" },
  { name: "ganguly" },
  { name: "laxman" }
];
var names = arr2.map(ob => ob.name);
console.log(arr1.filter(name => names.includes(name)));
```

Comment: Your answer is clear, concise and informative. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE11. _*ducks and runs away*_

Answer (score 1):

```
       const arr1 = ['john', 'robot'];
       const arr2 = [{name : 'john'}, {name : 'kevin'}, {name : 'james'}];
        var newArray= [];
        for(var i in arr2) {
            var content = arr2[i]['name'];
              if(arr1.indexOf(content) > -1){
                   newArray.push(content);
                }
        }

    console.log(newArray);
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a job for [`[].filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function doTheThingYouWantItToDo(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(elem) {
        for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i+=1) {
            if (b[i].name == elem) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Nested loops... ouch.

Comment: I forgot about [].indexOf, which I should've used instead.

Comment: `.indexOf` is still a loop over the entire array, so the complexity is still O(nm). Using a set however is only O(n+m) which is considerably faster and more efficient.